# Azure App Service deployed successfully, but the api website take a long time to got an changed

Tags: asp.net, continuous-deployment, .net-6.0, azure-deployment, azure-appservice

I have a .net 6 project and used Github action to make the continuous deployment. When I made changes and re-deployed it. The workflow run successful but The server takes a very long time(7-9 hours) to have a changed

I have been tried re-run the workflow but did not work

My workflow file

```
name: Build and deploy container app to Azure Web App - CityTourist

on:
 push:
  branches:
   - main
pull_request:
branches: [main]

workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
build:
runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Set up Docker Buildx
  uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

- name: Docker build and push
  uses: mr-smithers-excellent/docker-build-push@v5
  with:
    image: donephit/city-discover-tourist-server
    tags: v1, latest
    registry: docker.io
    username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

deploy:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
needs: build
environment:
  name: 'production'
  url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

steps:
- name: Deploy to Azure Web App
  id: deploy-to-webapp
  uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
  with:
    app-name: 'CityTourist'
    slot-name: 'production'
    publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_b411f9150dc04ec7a5df33a041e87f5f }}
    images: donephit/city-discover-tourist-server
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be frequently caused by application-level issues, such as slow network requests, inefficient application code or database queries, high memory/CPU usage, or application crashes due to an error.

Troubleshooting for this is divided into three different steps that must be followed in the following order:

1. Observe and monitor application behavior
2. Collect data
3. Mitigate the issue

Refer this troubleshoot [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-performance-degradation) for more information.